# How to get the scanner working on HP CM1312 MFP and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, printing, hp, scanner, hplip

I searched the AskUbuntu and got to two questions about the same issue, which I could not answer because I don't have enough karma :(. So I am posting the solution here.

After clean install, and installing the printer hplip, also install HPLIP Toolbox from the software centre.

Now, if you use 'Simple Scan' from the dash to scan a document, the HPToolbox will prompt you to install the required plugin. You can also install the plugin directly from the HPToolbox on the actions tab.

After this, my scanner works perfectly.

(Scan via network to pc).

Comment: care to link to the other question(s)? this is a Q&A site, so please don't post answers as questions.

Comment: Charl - there isnt anything in your profile that prevents you from actually posting an answer to a question.  Please do so, drop a link here so that this can be closed as a duplicate of the one you answered.  Thanks.